# Storring object and using it

Tags: java, object, rmi, instances

Is it possible in Java to store the object you want and change its values?

I am working on rmi server-client and I want to store my clients to an `ArrayList` on my server . It seemed good until I tried to change the client values directly from the server. If I was using C++ I would declare a pointer.

I call my method with `look_up.LogIn(this);`

**Server code :**

```
@Override
public void LogIn(Client temp) throws RemoteException {
    for (Client arr : users) {
        if (arr.equals(temp)) {
            temp.setID(0);
        }
    }
    // users.add(temp);
    Random rand = new Random();

    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((100 - 1) + 1) + 1;
    boolean flag = false;

    do {
        for (Client arr : users) {
            if (arr.getId() == randomNum) {
                flag = true;
            }
        }
    } while (flag);
    temp.setID(randomNum);
    System.out.println("Id we .. : " + temp.getId());
    users.add(temp);

}
```

**Client code :**

```
if (e.getSource() == logIn) {
    try {
        look_up.LogIn(this);
        if (this.id != 0) {                    
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Loged in Succesfully");
            logIn.setEnabled(false);
            submit.setEnabled(true);
            information.setText(look_up.check_Files());
            tempValue = this.id;
            System.out.println("Temp value afer login : " + tempValue);
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Sorry but somthing went wrong try to log in again...");
        }
    } catch (RemoteException ex) {
        System.err.println("Object cant be send");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

These lines of code work only if I define my `LogIn` as `int` and return the random number value. When I tried to change it directly I got an error.

The strange thing is that when I set the `temp.setId` it worked and printed fine but on clients actual instance id remained 0. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I can't make any sense out of your do-whole loop, but you seem to be expecting a parameter passed to the server to magically change its value at the client. This betrays a complete misunderstanding of what is happening. `Client` is clearly `Serializable`, so it is passed by value to the server. Any change made to that object at the server will *not* be mirrored at the cliens. If you want a result you have to return it from the remote method as a result value.